# Does postgres efficiently re-use space from deleted rows?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, vacuum

From [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY):

> In PostgreSQL, an UPDATE or DELETE of a row **does not immediately remove the old version** of the row [...] But eventually, an outdated or deleted row version is no longer of interest to any transaction. The space it occupies must then be reclaimed for reuse by new rows, to avoid unbounded growth of disk space requirements. This is done **by running VACUUM**.

When vacuum runs, does it efficiently free the space occupied by the deleted rows by rewriting the entire block, or does block fragmentation occur with new rows fitting into available 'holes' only if they are smaller than the deleted row that has made way for them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VACUUM rewrites the entire block, efficiently packing the remaining rows and leaving a single contiguous block of free space (though this space isn't zeroed and the physical disk file might contain the remnants of deleted rows which of course are in no way visible to the database user).

test schema:

```
--#psql postgres postgres
select oid from pg_database where datname='postgres';
/*
  oid
-------
 12035
*/
create schema stack;
set search_path=stack;
create table foo(bar text);
insert into stack.foo(bar) values('row 1');
insert into stack.foo(bar) values('row 2');
checkpoint;
select * from foo;
/*
  bar
-------
 row 1
 row 2
*/
select relfilenode
from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on n.oid=c.relnamespace
where nspname='stack' and relname='foo';
/*
 relfilenode
-------------
      446488
*/
```

physical contents of table backing file:

```
xxd -a /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/base/12035/446488

0000000: 3800 0000 f093 9d83 0000 0000 2000 c01f  8........... ...
0000010: 0020 0420 0000 0000 e09f 3c00 c09f 3c00  . . ......<...<.
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
0001fc0: 2176 4c14 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  !vL.............
0001fd0: 0200 0100 0208 1800 0d72 6f77 2032 0000  .........row 2.. <---- this is row 2
0001fe0: 2176 4c14 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  !vL.............
0001ff0: 0100 0100 0208 1800 0d72 6f77 2031 0000  .........row 1..
```

delete and vacuum:

```
delete from foo where bar='row 1';
vacuum stack.foo;
checkpoint;
```

physical contents of table backing file:

```
xxd -a /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/base/12035/446488

0000000: 3800 0000 e8b5 9e83 0000 0500 2000 e01f  8........... ...
0000010: 0020 0420 0000 0000 0000 0000 e09f 3c00  . . ..........<.
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
0001fc0: 2176 4c14 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  !vL.............
0001fd0: 0200 0100 0209 1800 0d72 6f77 2032 0000  .........row 2.. <---- this is free space
0001fe0: 2176 4c14 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  !vL.............
0001ff0: 0200 0100 0209 1800 0d72 6f77 2032 0000  .........row 2..
```

insert new row:

```
insert into stack.foo(bar) values('row 3');
checkpoint;
```

final physical contents of table backing file:

```
xxd -a /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/base/12035/446488

0000000: 3800 0000 c8ec 9e83 0000 0100 2000 c01f  8........... ...
0000010: 0020 0420 0000 0000 c09f 3c00 e09f 3c00  . . ......<...<.
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
0001fc0: 2476 4c14 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  $vL.............
0001fd0: 0100 0100 0208 1800 0d72 6f77 2033 0000  .........row 3.. <---- this is row 3
0001fe0: 2176 4c14 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  !vL.............
0001ff0: 0200 0100 0209 1800 0d72 6f77 2032 0000  .........row 2..
```

clean up:

```
drop schema stack cascade;
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting ! After running vacuum , the "row 2" will push down "row 1" previous and the "row 2" previous will empty. And if we use "vacuum full stack.foo", the "row 1" will delete from physical disk.

Comment: Yes, `vacuum full` writes a new table so no 'junk' data (un-zeroed free space) will survive.